# How to delete the last row of data of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I think this should be simple, but I tried a few ideas and none of them worked:

```
last_row = len(DF)
DF = DF.drop(DF.index[last_row])  #<-- fail!
```

I tried using negative indices but that also lead to errors. I must still be misunderstanding something basic.

Comment: `DF = DF[:-1]`?

Comment: @U2EF1 this copies the entire dataset, doesnt it? When handling huge data this may be an issue.

Comment: if last_row is taking the length of DF, then you need to use (last_row-1) for indexing.

Comment: It's good practice to use `df.shape[0]` rather than `len(df)` to get the number of rows.

Comment: Why is that good practice @pabz?

Comment: @Tavin I am coming from a data science perspective where the pandas package is central, so this might be a bit opinionated.  Being cognizant of your data shapes is always good.  However it appears `len` is faster just running a quick test in a notebook.

Answer (score 326):

To drop last n rows:

```
df.drop(df.tail(n).index,inplace=True) # drop last n rows
```

By the same vein, you can drop first n rows:

```
df.drop(df.head(n).index,inplace=True) # drop first n rows
```

Comment: To drop the last column you can use df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True) or, if you know the name of the column you can use df.drop(columns=['col_name'], inplace=True) - if you do not want it to be performed in place, assign it to a new variable and remove that argument.

Comment: This method only works if the index of the last row is unique, as it removes all the rows that have the same index as the last n rows. @blue-sky 's  answer seems more appropriate

Answer (score 213):

```
DF[:-n]
```

where n is the last number of rows to drop.

To drop the last row :

```
DF = DF[:-1]
```

Comment: This works, but I suspect Wes McKinney wouldn't like it.  Why not use the stuff built into Pandas?

Comment: Maybe deprecated because I got an error, it was looking for a column named `-1`. Had to use  `df = df.iloc[:-1]`

Comment: According to my tests, this is at least 6 times faster than using `.drop()`!

Comment: Does this create a view or a copy? Possibly explains the speed difference if it's a view.

Answer (score 62):

Since index positioning in Python is 0-based, there won't actually be an element in `index` at the location corresponding to `len(DF)`. You need that to be `last_row = len(DF) - 1`:

```
In [49]: dfrm
Out[49]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.120064  0.785538  0.465853
1  0.431655  0.436866  0.640136
2  0.445904  0.311565  0.934073
3  0.981609  0.695210  0.911697
4  0.008632  0.629269  0.226454
5  0.577577  0.467475  0.510031
6  0.580909  0.232846  0.271254
7  0.696596  0.362825  0.556433
8  0.738912  0.932779  0.029723
9  0.834706  0.002989  0.333436

[10 rows x 3 columns]

In [50]: dfrm.drop(dfrm.index[len(dfrm)-1])
Out[50]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.120064  0.785538  0.465853
1  0.431655  0.436866  0.640136
2  0.445904  0.311565  0.934073
3  0.981609  0.695210  0.911697
4  0.008632  0.629269  0.226454
5  0.577577  0.467475  0.510031
6  0.580909  0.232846  0.271254
7  0.696596  0.362825  0.556433
8  0.738912  0.932779  0.029723

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

However, it's much simpler to just write `DF[:-1]`.

Comment: Note that when dropping using dfrm.index, the index of the last row should be unique, otherwise all rows with that index are dropped.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that using drop (inplace=True) you modifiy the existing df, while using df[:-1] you get a view of data, which later can lead to SettingWithCopyWarning?

Answer (score 61):

Surprised nobody brought this one up:

```py
# To remove last n rows
df.head(-n)

# To remove first n rows
df.tail(-n)
```

Running a speed test on a DataFrame of 1000 rows shows that slicing and `head`/`tail` are ~6 times faster than using `drop`:

```py
>>> %timeit df[:-1]
125 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.head(-1)
129 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.drop(df.tail(1).index)
751 µs ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Maybe the difference between both approaches is that `head()` and `tail()` create a _view_ whereas `drop()` actually changes representation in memory (either inplace modification, or creates an entirely new dataframe). I did not look this up in docs, someone please do. (if that's the difference: good explanation for perf diff, and one needs to carefully choose between them)/

Comment: @Dr.Jan-PhilipGehrcke Head `head`, `tail` and `drop` all return a view, although it's true that `drop` gives you the option to modify the original dataframe inplace.

Answer (score 17):

Just use indexing

```
df.iloc[:-1,:]
```

That's why iloc exists. You can also use head or tail.

Comment: Consider expanding on your answer and explaining how and why your solution works

Answer (score 14):

The nicest solution I've found that doesn't (necessarily?) do a fully copy is

```
df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
```

Of course, you can simply omit `inplace=True` to create a new dataframe, and you can also easily delete the last `N` rows by simply taking slices of `df.index` (`df.index[-N:]` to drop the last N rows). So this approach is not only concise but also very flexible.

Answer (score 8):

```
stats = pd.read_csv("C:\\py\\programs\\second pandas\\ex.csv")
```

The Output of stats:

```
       A            B          C
0   0.120064    0.785538    0.465853
1   0.431655    0.436866    0.640136
2   0.445904    0.311565    0.934073
3   0.981609    0.695210    0.911697
4   0.008632    0.629269    0.226454
5   0.577577    0.467475    0.510031
6   0.580909    0.232846    0.271254
7   0.696596    0.362825    0.556433
8   0.738912    0.932779    0.029723
9   0.834706    0.002989    0.333436
```

just use `skipfooter=1`

> skipfooter : int, default 0
>
> Number of lines at bottom of file to skip

```
stats_2 = pd.read_csv("C:\\py\\programs\\second pandas\\ex.csv", skipfooter=1, engine='python')
```

Output of stats_2

```
       A          B            C
0   0.120064    0.785538    0.465853
1   0.431655    0.436866    0.640136
2   0.445904    0.311565    0.934073
3   0.981609    0.695210    0.911697
4   0.008632    0.629269    0.226454
5   0.577577    0.467475    0.510031
6   0.580909    0.232846    0.271254
7   0.696596    0.362825    0.556433
8   0.738912    0.932779    0.029723
```

Answer (score 2):

you know what, you just need to gave -1 in first line, like this

```
last_row = len(DF) - 1
DF = DF.drop(DF.index[last_row])
```

Answer (score 0):

drop returns a new array so that is why it choked in the og post; I had a similar requirement to rename some column headers and deleted some rows due to an ill formed csv file converted to Dataframe, so after reading this post I used:

```
newList = pd.DataFrame(newList)
newList.columns = ['Area', 'Price']
print(newList)
# newList = newList.drop(0)
# newList = newList.drop(len(newList))
newList = newList[1:-1]
print(newList)
```

and it worked great, as you can see with the two commented out lines above I tried the drop.() method and it work but not as kool and readable as using [n:-n], hope that helps someone, thanks.

Comment: It's exactly the same as many other answers already present.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex DataFrames that have a Multi-Index (say "Stock" and "Date") and one wants to remove the last row for each Stock not just the last row of the last Stock, then the solution reads:

```
# To remove last n rows
df = df.groupby(level='Stock').apply(lambda x: x.head(-1)).reset_index(0, drop=True)

# To remove first n rows
df = df.groupby(level='Stock').apply(lambda x: x.tail(-1)).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

As the `groupby()` is adding an additional level to the Multi-Index we just drop it at the end using `reset_index()`. The resulting df keeps the same type of Multi-Index as before the operation.

Answer (score 0):

DF.drop((labels=None, axis=0, index = last_row)

as a function of:

DataFrame.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')

Drop specified labels from rows or columns.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), 
[see also Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).