# Removing header and footer from the excel file when creating the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have to read an excel file to dataframe for doing some analysis. But this excel file has header and footer and need to be removed. How can I remove them once I read them as datagram.

[image: Screenshot of the excel file]

Answer (score 0):

The header and footer of the dataframe can't be removed when you read the file, but you can slice the old one and assigned it to a new dataframe.

For the screenshot what you can do is.

```
temp_data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
data = temp_date[12:]
```

check this document: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-with-labels

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a new sheet in Excel with only the data. :)

**Option 1: Ignore the header with header offset**

```
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', header=18)
```

Explanation:

> If you pass the header value as an integer, let’s say 3. Then the third row will be treated as the header row and the values will be read from the next row onwards. Any data before the header row will be discarded.

source: https://www.journaldev.com/33306/pandas-read_excel-reading-excel-file-in-python

**Option 2: Remove header with drop**

`df.drop(df.head(18).index,inplace=True) # drop first 18 rows`

**Drop Footer**

Then simply drop the last rows:

```
df.drop(df.tail(n).index,inplace=True) # drop last n rows
```

source: [How to delete the last row of data of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921651/how-to-delete-the-last-row-of-data-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you that it's better to use skiprows when importing the file. The instruction would be like this:

```
dataframe = pd.read_excel('xxfile.xls', skiprows=XX, usecols="C:F")
```